# How to get multiple DNS Geo balancing entry points

Tags: linux, cdn, architecture

I am facing a problem. I will set up a CDN with multiple dedicated servers in multiple zones (Asia, US, Eu), and I will set up an entry point with Nginx proxy with geoip routing.

But with this solution I just move the problem higher. Because this load balancer needs to be somewhere in the world ... if I set it in US, the Asia traffic will be very poor and vice versa...

I see solution like GeoDNS by clouddns but I don't understand how it is working ...

Has someone already solved this issue ? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some DNS hosting providers (and when you host your own dns some products allow you to do the same) allow you to set up geodns where, depending on the source IP-address of a dns requests, you can tailor the response.

For  example when users request `www.example.com` you can return the CNAME www-us.example.com for US users and CNAME www-ap.example.com for users from Asia Pacific. For most users that will result that although they all use [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) in their browser URL bar, they will be directed to specific  servers that are then geographically nearby.

Like any IP to geographic location scheme that won’t be completely fool proof and accurate, but it should work as intended for a large part of your user base.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Cloud DNS, but Amazon web services provides a similar service with Route 53. They provide several differentiation keys, like location of the asking IP address, or measured latency between that IP address and a number of Amazon data centers. Based on that, you can give different IP addresses back as result.

You may need to change your DNS hosting to a new provider, or use sub zone delegation, if you can afford using a subdomain name on your domain (hard if you're talking about a website's address, but doable when you load website assets from `cdn.website.com` for instance.

Comment: I am very sure the route 53 needs to use geodata and know where that ip come from = geodns

Comment: @c4f4t0r Yes and no. The DNS servers they offer are anycast, so the same IP is something else everywhere. They can measure the latency between that end node and several AWS data centers. Based on that, it can determine what AWS data center works best. This works well if your services are hosted in those AWS data centers. So, it's not IP geodata as such, but it's region dependent.

Comment: route 53 has Geolocation routing and for this, they need to take the location of user, anyway If I want to setup my own cdn, I will go with geodns and distributed servers and every region + storage replication